# How to convert this VBScript string to a PHP string

Tags: php, string, vbscript

Here is the VBScript I want to convert to PHP:

```
Dim buffer = New String("")
buffer = buffer &("<Section name=""GLOBAL"" >" )
```

I know double double quotes are to escape so I tried backslash in PHP instead of double double quotes.

```
$buffer .= '("<Section name=\"GLOBAL\" >" )';
```

The PHP output is : `("" )`

Please help. Thanks everyone !

Comment: Look at the page source. You browser is not showing the tag, but just the rest ...

Comment: Well I'll be damned, hahaha! thanks dude! +1 to you sir